# Teradata SQL: Displaying data at specified time interval through self joins

Tags: sql, teradata

I built this long query that essentially self joins a bunch of tables but at different time frames to pull in balances at 3 month intervals and places each balance / time period combination in its own column.

The query is something like this:

```
select
   extract(year from a.mnth_end_dt) * 100 + extract(month from a.mnth_end_dt) as YM
  ,case when s.segmt_id = 'S4' then 'A'
        else 'R'
        end as Segment
  ,case when a.act_open_dt between add_months(a.mnth_end_dt + interval '1' day, -1) and a.mnth_end_dt then 'New'
        else 'Old'
        end as ACT_STAT  
  ,count(distinct a.act_id) as ACTs
  ,coalesce(sum(b0.b1),0) as INT0_Tot_BD_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(bk0.bal),0) as INT0_Tot_BNK_Cash
  ,INT0_Tot_BD_Assets + INT0_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT0_Tot_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(b0.b2),0) as INT0_BS
  ,coalesce(sum(b0.b3),0) as INT0_BDC 
  ,INT0_BS + INT0_BDC + INT0_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT0_Tot_Cash
  ,cast(cast(INT0_Tot_Cash as decimal(20,4)) / cast(INT0_Tot_Assets as decimal(20,4)) as decimal(20,4)) * 100 || '%' as INT0_Cash_Pct  
  ,coalesce(sum(b1.b1),0) as INT1_Tot_BD_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(bk1.bal),0) as INT1_Tot_BNK_Cash
  ,INT1_Tot_BD_Assets + INT1_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT1_Tot_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(b1.b2),0) as INT1_BS
  ,coalesce(sum(b1.b3),0) as INT1_BDC  
  ,INT1_BS + INT1_BDC + INT1_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT1_Tot_Cash
  ,case when INT1_Tot_Cash = 0 then 0 || '%' 
        else cast(cast(INT1_Tot_Cash as decimal(20,4)) / cast(INT1_Tot_Assets as decimal(20,4)) as decimal(20,4)) * 100 || '%' 
        end as INT1_Cash_Pct  
  ,coalesce(sum(b2.b1),0) as INT2_Tot_BD_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(bk2.bal),0) as INT2_Tot_BNK_Cash
  ,INT2_Tot_BD_Assets + INT2_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT2_Tot_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(b2.b2),0) as INT2_BS
  ,coalesce(sum(b2.b3),0) as INT2_BDC  
  ,INT2_BS + INT2_BDC + INT2_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT2_Tot_Cash
  ,case when INT2_Tot_Cash = 0 then 0 || '%' 
        else cast(cast(INT2_Tot_Cash as decimal(20,4)) / cast(INT2_Tot_Assets as decimal(20,4)) as decimal(20,4)) * 100 || '%' 
        end as INT2_Cash_Pct  

  from or.accts a

    inner join ir.segments s
      on a.clnt_cd = c.clnt_cd --segmt_lvl_nm# (6 highest level: AS/IS/Other Business)                
      and c.segmt_id in ('S4','S5')

    left join ir.acct_bal_mthly b0
      on a.acct_id = b0.acct_id      
      and b0.mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from a.mnth_end_dt) * 100 + (extract(month from a.mnth_end_dt)) as integer)

    left join ir.acct_bal_mthly b1
      on a.acct_id = b1.acct_id      
      and b1.mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3))) as integer)

    left join ir.acct_bal_mthly_1 b2
      on a.acct_id = b2.acct_id      
      and b2.mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6))) as integer)    

    left join br.bank_bal_mnth bk0
      on a.s_acct_id = bk0.bk_acct_nbr      
      and bk0.busn_dt = a.mnth_end_dt

    left join br.bank_bal_mnth bk1
      on a.s_acct_id = bk1.bk_acct_nbr      
      and bk1.busn_dt = (add_months(a.mnth_end_dt + interval '1' day, 3) - interval '1' day)

    left join br.bank_bal_mnth bk2
      on a.s_acct_id = bk2.bk_acct_nbr      
      and bk2.busn_dt = (add_months(a.mnth_end_dt + interval '1' day, 6) - interval '1' day)

  where a.mnth_end_dt between '2014-01-31' and '2018-04-30'        
    and a.acct_clos_dt is null    

group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2,3
```

This query gets the job done, but I'm wondering if there is a better / more efficient way to do this?  I feel that this query would unnecessarily tax the server (the actual query is much larger, I shortened it here for this question).

Would appreciate any ideas.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the same table is joined multiple times with the same join-conditions and different additional conditions it can be replaced by a single join plus  *conditional aggregation*:

```
select
...
   ,sum(case when bk.busn_dt = a.mnth_end_dt                 then bk.bal else 0) as INT0_Tot_BNK_Cash
...
   ,sum(case when bk.busn_dt = oadd_months(a.mnth_end_dt, 3) then bk.bal else 0) as INT1_Tot_BNK_Cash
...
   ,sum(case when bk.busn_dt = oadd_months(a.mnth_end_dt, 6) then bk.bal else 0) as INT2_Tot_BNK_Cash
...

left join br.bank_bal_mnth bk
  on a.s_acct_id = bk.bk_acct_nbr      
  and (   bk.busn_dt = a.mnth_end_dt
       or bk.busn_dt = oadd_months(a.mnth_end_dt, 3)
       or bk.busn_dt = oadd_months(a.mnth_end_dt, 6)
      )
```

`oadd_months(a.mnth_end_dt, 3)` is a rewrite of `(add_months(a.mnth_end_dt + interval '1' day, 3) - interval '1' day)`

Similar for the joins to `acct_bal_mthly`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this approach and the query takes about twice as long to run with this approach vs. self joining the tables multiple times with different arguments (my original approach).  Any idea why?  The DBA even sent me an email to abort the query as it was using too many resources :)

Comment: @starfly: You're probably joining over the Primary Index and Partitioning,then the `or`ed join might be less efficient, check Explain.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional logic like below.  I demonstrated by commenting out table with alias b2 for you and replacing with case statements in the corresponsing selects.  Repeat same logic for bk1 and bk2 as well.  Will probably need a bit of formatting too sorry...

```
select
   extract(year from a.mnth_end_dt) * 100 + extract(month from a.mnth_end_dt) as YM
  ,case when s.segmt_id = 'S4' then 'A'
        else 'R'
        end as Segment
  ,case when a.act_open_dt between add_months(a.mnth_end_dt + interval '1' day, -1) and a.mnth_end_dt then 'New'
        else 'Old'
        end as ACT_STAT  
  ,count(distinct a.act_id) as ACTs
  ,coalesce(sum(b0.b1),0) as INT0_Tot_BD_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(bk0.bal),0) as INT0_Tot_BNK_Cash
  ,INT0_Tot_BD_Assets + INT0_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT0_Tot_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(b0.b2),0) as INT0_BS
  ,coalesce(sum(b0.b3),0) as INT0_BDC 
  ,INT0_BS + INT0_BDC + INT0_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT0_Tot_Cash
  ,cast(cast(INT0_Tot_Cash as decimal(20,4)) / cast(INT0_Tot_Assets as decimal(20,4)) as decimal(20,4)) * 100 || '%' as INT0_Cash_Pct  
  ,coalesce(sum(case when b1.mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3))) as integer)),0) then b1 else null end),
  ,coalesce(sum(bk1.bal),0) as INT1_Tot_BNK_Cash
  ,INT1_Tot_BD_Assets + INT1_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT1_Tot_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(case when b1.mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3))) as integer)),0) then b2 else null end),
  ,coalesce(sum(case when b1.mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3))) as integer)),0) then b3 else null end),
  ,INT1_BS + INT1_BDC + INT1_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT1_Tot_Cash
  ,case when INT1_Tot_Cash = 0 then 0 || '%' 
        else cast(cast(INT1_Tot_Cash as decimal(20,4)) / cast(INT1_Tot_Assets as decimal(20,4)) as decimal(20,4)) * 100 || '%' 
        end as INT1_Cash_Pct  
  ,coalesce(sum(case when mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6))) as integer)),0) then b1 else null end),
  ,coalesce(sum(bk2.bal),0) as INT2_Tot_BNK_Cash
  ,INT2_Tot_BD_Assets + INT2_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT2_Tot_Assets
  ,coalesce(sum(case when mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6))) as integer)),0) then b2 else null end),
  ,coalesce(sum(case when mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6))) as integer)),0) then b3 else null end), 
  ,INT2_BS + INT2_BDC + INT2_Tot_BNK_Cash as INT2_Tot_Cash
  ,case when INT2_Tot_Cash = 0 then 0 || '%' 
        else cast(cast(INT2_Tot_Cash as decimal(20,4)) / cast(INT2_Tot_Assets as decimal(20,4)) as decimal(20,4)) * 100 || '%' 
        end as INT2_Cash_Pct  

  from or.accts a

    inner join ir.segments s
      on a.clnt_cd = c.clnt_cd --segmt_lvl_nm# (6 highest level: AS/IS/Other Business)                
      and c.segmt_id in ('S4','S5')

    left join ir.acct_bal_mthly b0
      on a.acct_id = b0.acct_id      
      and b0.mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from a.mnth_end_dt) * 100 + (extract(month from a.mnth_end_dt)) as integer)

    left join ir.acct_bal_mthly b1
      on a.acct_id = b1.acct_id      
      and b1.mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,3))) as integer)

    --left join ir.acct_bal_mthly_1 b2
     -- on a.acct_id = b2.acct_id      
    --  and b2.mnth_end_yyyymm = cast(extract(year from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6)) * 100 + (extract(month from add_months(a.mnth_end_dt,6))) as integer)    

    left join br.bank_bal_mnth bk0
      on a.s_acct_id = bk0.bk_acct_nbr      
      and bk0.busn_dt = a.mnth_end_dt

    left join br.bank_bal_mnth bk1
      on a.s_acct_id = bk1.bk_acct_nbr      
      and bk1.busn_dt = (add_months(a.mnth_end_dt + interval '1' day, 3) - interval '1' day)

    left join br.bank_bal_mnth bk2
      on a.s_acct_id = bk2.bk_acct_nbr      
      and bk2.busn_dt = (add_months(a.mnth_end_dt + interval '1' day, 6) - interval '1' day)

  where a.mnth_end_dt between '2014-01-31' and '2018-04-30'        
    and a.acct_clos_dt is null    

group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2,3
```